# Moving from requirejs to systemjs: managing paths

Tags: systemjs

I'm in the process of migrating to systemjs, mainly given it's support of modules which makes moving to ES6 simpler.

The systemjs CSS plugin allows for elegant imports like this:

```
System.import('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!');
```

But this loads asynchronously, so it's not practical for loading CSS that needs to be loaded before the rest of the server-generated page. So I have to revert to cumbersome package URLs. (which will break when versions change -- and seems to be generally quite hacky -- since JSPM is supposed to be managing these details?)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/res/packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Is there a best practice? In fact, are there any useful examples of the practical use of systemjs?

Answer (score 2):

You might hide the body, create a javascript module that loads your assets and show the body when the assets have loaded:

**assets.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!';
```

Then in your **index.html** file:

```
System.import('assets.js').then(function(){
   //Now your styles are loaded. You may fade in/display your content.
   document.querySelector('body').style.display = 'block';
}); //Add the JS extension according to your SystemJS configuration
```

Comment: I got a bit nervous when the first line of the first comment began with "you might hide the body"

Comment: I would never do that.